# Javascript closure capture

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have following code:

```
var i;

for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

This obviously prints numbers from 1 to 10 just fine. Then I want to do this asynchronously:

```
var i;

for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    setImmediate(function() { console.log(i); });
}
```

And here it is — it prints only 11-s. First I was wondering if this is some shared state problem (it happened when I tried to fetch multiple pages with PhantomJS, and ended fetching the same one N times, so I've thought something is not quite async-safe there), then compacted the issue up to example shown above, then understood it's because javascript closures don't seem to capture their environment — so despite the fact I used `i` in function, it uses actual value of `i` at the moment of execution, which is, indeed, 11.

Unfortunately, due to design of API, I'm unable to pass additional parameters to callbacks to make `i` local to function, as I can't change the signature.

So, question is — how to rewrite second example to work correctly?

Comment: This is the famous closure loop problem. You can do `.bind(i)`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum isn't `.bind(null, i)` preferable ?

Comment: Yeah yeah. That's the one.

Comment: " javascript closures don't seem to capture their environment" no, your problem is that they do. That's what a closure is. What they don't do is create a new reference. Function signatures can do that when the function is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an annonymous wrapper for this:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    (function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(e);  
        }, 1000);
    })(i);
}
```

The anonymous outer function gets called immediately with i as its first argument and will receive a copy of the value of i as its parameter e.
The anonymous function that gets passed to setTimeout now has a reference to e, whose value does not get changed by the loop.

Another way of doing this is:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    setTimeout((function(e) {
        return function() {
            console.log(e);
        }
    })(i), 1000)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems much better than binding value to `this`, as `this` itself may be useful.

Comment: @modchan: Doesn't matter. If you don't bind `this`, then it will just get the default value. A function doesn't keep the `this` value of its enclosing environment, unless you're using ECMAScript 6 fat arrow function syntax. So if you need a useful `this`, you might as well use `.bind()`.

Comment: @cookiemonster, sorry, my fault.

Answer (score 1):

To understand this problem, you need to realize that a closure captures the *variable* itself not the *value* of the variable at the time the function is created. Therefore, every function created inside the loop closes over the *same* `i` (whose value is `11` at the end of the loop).

In order to have each function close over a *its own* variable, you need to introduce a new scope, which in javascript is done using functions. Like this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    (function(c) {
        setImmediate(function() { console.log(i); });
    })(i);
}
```

Now `i` is scoped to its nearest containing function (which is the same for each iteration) and the parameter `c` is scoped to its nearest containing function (which is a new function during each iteration).